# How can i pass an argument as string with line break \n in EvaluateJavascript?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I'm having an issue when using the `EvaluteJavascript` on both `Android and iOS` (I'm using `Xamarin`).

The issue is when I want to pass a string argument to a `javascript` function, if that string contains special character, the js compiler will not understand.

For example:

```
EvaluateJavascript("updateHtml('Some Html \n Some Html')")
```

But if i use, this will work:

```
EvaluateJavascript("updateHtml('Some Html Some Html')")
```

So the question is how am i able to pass entire string as argument to the javascript function in EvaluateJavascript.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you tried storing it in an object ?

Comment: what do you mean by "js compiler will not understand". does it show the output or  fails to show output?

Comment: Hi, storing it in an object will not work since it's the same to put it's as the function.
The js compiler will not understand meaning it will not understand the entire string as a variable pass into the function, imaging it's like when you write a javascript function with a line break, but not a "\n" into the variable.
The WebView in Android doesn't return anything but only a "null" string back.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue.

I encoded my string as URL encoding like this

```
EvaluateJavascript('$"updateHtml({Uri.EscapeUriString("Some Html \n Some Html"'})))
```

Then in my javascript i just need to decode it by using:

```
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = decodeURI(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using "\\n" instead of "\n" ?